# How to access rows in pandas by name with loc? ValueError: No axis named XXX for object type DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the data that i am working on the below is the DataFrame in pandas here the index of the rows are string

```
   Openness     Conscientiousness   Extroversion    Agreeableness   Neuroticism
Root    0.139050    0.000000    0.325481    0.147281    0.169475
Hips    0.530089    0.477398    0.804277    0.547530    0.686413
Knee    0.869004    1.000000    0.662191    0.936127    1.000000
Ankle   0.964990    0.723205    0.638736    1.000000    0.735433
Toe     0.982430    0.590160    0.851289    0.893272    0.970389
Torso   0.551036    0.372635    0.489920    0.638199    0.611516
Neck    0.000000    0.057604    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Head    0.837630    0.502632    0.839598    0.555689    0.797577
Shoulder    0.318785    0.540544    0.844912    0.418395    0.347727
Elbow   0.861450    0.613711    1.000000    0.941450    0.902488
Wrist   0.505890    0.404177    0.477072    0.267725    0.626525
Finger  1.000000    0.708020    0.825508    0.573568    0.757162
```

When i am doing SET1 is the name of DataFrame
`print(SET1.loc('Root'))`
I am getting KeyError

```
ValueError: No axis named Root for object type DataFrame
```

Comment: the syntax is `SET1.loc['Root']`, with square brackets

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, use square brackets with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc['Root'] # using df here in place of SET1
```

Now there are also cases where you can **call** loc (using parentheses)

`loc` is a property than returns a `LocIndexer`

```
@property
def loc(self) -> _LocIndexer:
    return _LocIndexer("loc", self)
```

If you look at the code, `loc` is both **callable** and **indexable**/**sliceable** (and actually more).

The `_LocIndexer`/`_LocationIndexer` object returned by `loc` enable to specify the axis on which to slice/index/…

```
class _LocationIndexer(NDFrameIndexerBase):
    _valid_types: str
    axis = None

    def __call__(self, axis=None):
        # we need to return a copy of ourselves
        new_self = type(self)(self.name, self.obj)

        if axis is not None:
            axis = self.obj._get_axis_number(axis)
        new_self.axis = axis
        return new_self
```

Which means you can do:

```
df.loc(axis=0)['Root']
# OR
df.loc(axis=1)['Root']
```

to select the axis on which to index

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages `()` parenthesis after a name or keyword indicate a call of a function. `loc` doesn't work like that. You are attempting to access data in a dataframe, that is done in the same way as f you were accessing data in a list or similar data structure. By using `[]` parenthesis.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

In you case you may want to try `SET1.loc['Root']` and see where that takes you.

Comment: Actually `loc` can take parameters to define the axis to use, so you could do `loc(axis=0)['Root']`

Comment: I provided some more details as answer for clarity